# Exclude files using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-negation

i want to exclude all `.mp3` and `.jpeg` files (with a regular expression, **not** PHP). I know about `!preg_match`)

My example below always matches:

```
$str = 'file.mp3'; // Exclude
$ex  = '~(?!\.(mp3|jpe?g))$~';

if (preg_match($ex, $str)) {
    echo "Match!";
} else {
    echo "Nothing Match!";
}
```

Comment: if you're not using PHP, why is it in the tags?

Answer (score 2):

Your negative lookahead isn't working because there is nothing to look ahead at. Remember that lookaround assertions are zero-width — they do not actually consume characters. You will still need to account for the filename extension characters.

Change the expression as follows:

```
$ex = '~(?!\.(mp3|jpe?g))[a-z]{3,4}$~';
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/158087)

---

A better approach would be to use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) though. Maintain an array of extensions that you'd like to disallow and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to check if the extension of the filename is *in* that array:

```
$disallowed = ['mp3', 'jpg', 'jpeg', /* more extensions */ ];

if (in_array(pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $disallowed)) {
    # code...
}
```